# How can I make flex share the width of my svg evenly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have problem with my flex div in my portfolio. I have 3 services that I want to feature. They all have a svg image and some text underneath. I tried to give them all a `flex: 1` property, but they still don't share the space evenly.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="flex flex-row">
    <div class="px-24 pt-8 flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center items-center text-center">
        <img src="/static/media/design.0e806bbe.svg">
        <span class="font-montserrat font-bold text-4xl">Design</span>
    </div>
    <div class="px-24 pt-8 flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center items-center text-center">
        <img src="/static/media/code.4871712c.svg">
        <span class="font-montserrat font-bold text-4xl">Programmation</span>
    </div>
    <div class="px-24 pt-8 flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center items-center text-center">
        <img src="/static/media/hosting.af9efcf1.svg">
        <span class="font-montserrat font-bold text-4xl">Hébergement</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I get:
[image: screenshot]

PS: I am using TailwindCSS.

Comment: Try to add this CSS poperty called `object-fit` to your element and set it to *cover* like so: `object-fit: cover;`. I would sugest that you force your images to have some sort of ratio and then use this to ensure exact continuity in your portfolio. The reason I'm saying this is that the CSS property I gave you will keep the aspect ratio of the image the best it can, so if you make sure that every image at least start out in a compatible aspect ratio with one another, then you're settled pretty much. If you're using Bootstrap, then there's also some neat classes to play around with there.

Comment: @Martin Unfortunately, it didn't work...

Comment: It should work. It should make the image fit the container while keeping the aspect ratio of the image that you're using. What I would suggest is that you set yourself a kind of "Design Guide/Manual", i.e. "My portfolio images will have aspect ratio x times y" and edit your images to always follow that standard. Then have your containers follow a specific set of grid, and then the CSS rule I gave you should 100% apply.

Comment: The problem is that the div that contain the image are set to the width of the images, so it doesn't changes anything when I had this property.

Comment: That's the wrong way of thinking. Have your containers be specific, because that way you will have an easier time controlling the responsiveness. Make your images fit the container, and not the other way around. It will save you a lot of future headaches if you want a specific grid layout that's supposed to always be in a specific way. I would either make use of Flexbox Grid, or Bootstrap Grid.

Comment: If you wanna make your own flexbox grid: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/ and here if you wanna use existing flexbox grid framework: http://flexboxgrid.com/ and here if you wanna use bootstrap grid (you will need Bootstrap CSS for this): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/